# Making child forms stay inside the main form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm having a problem keeping my child forms inside my main form. My current problem is that the user can drag the child form out of the main form, and I don't want for the application to allow that, I want the child form to stay inside the main form only. In the main form, I'm creating and calling the child form like this:

```
newForm^ form = gcnew newForm;
form->Show();
```

My child form's FormBorderStyle is set to none, so to be able to drag it I'm using this code on mouseMove:

```
private: System::Void newForm_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {

         if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
         {
             this->Top = MousePosition.Y;
             this->Left = MousePosition.X;
         }

    }
```

But how can I make it so that the user can't the drag the child form outside the main form?

Edit: Already tried Mdi Containers but it's not working for me since it messes up my form's colors and transparency on most of my controls.

Comment: It is a pre-cooked windowing model that's already available in Winforms.  You can use the IsMdiContainer property on the main window, the MdiParent property on the child windows.  Pretty unfriendly in C++/CLI btw, the forward declarations you need on the child form classes are a headache.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried with Mdi Containers before but setting a form's IsMdiContainer property to true messes up my form's colors and transparency on most of the controls. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Lots of libraries around that help you implement a docking layout windowing model, similar to the way VS works.  But you probably already tried those as well and didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I forgot to mention it on my question, I'll edit it. The Mdi containers were the only thing I've tried though, I don't know of any other solutions.